TypeORM findOne() security vulnerability
Is typeorm vulnerable with find one in this case ?
const job = await this.jobRepository.findOne({ where: { id: task.jobId } });
This is issue reported by our SAST:
  "identifiers": [ { "type": "semgrep_id", "name": "nodejs_scan.javascript-database-rule-node_nosqli_injection", "value": "nodejs_scan.javascript-database-rule-node_nosqli_injection" }, { "type": "cwe", "name": "CWE-943", "value": "943", "url": "https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/943.html" }, { "type": "owasp", "name": "A03:2021 - Injection", "value": "A03:2021" }, { "type": "owasp", "name": "A1:2017 - Injection", "value": "A1:2017" }, { "type": "njsscan_rule_type", "name": "NodeJS Scan ID javascript-database-rule-node_nosqli_injection", "value": "Untrusted user input in findOne() function can result in NoSQL Injection." } ]
Is it a false positive ? Does typeorm escape the where conditions ?
